# Multiple forms rendered in one page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Index view, I render(action) 3 other views, Create, Edit and List. The Create and Edit views are both forms to manipulate data in a database. When I push edit button in the List View the Create form should disappears and the Edit form should appear. So Create and Edit shouldn't be shown at the same time.

When I don't render the views in one view, everything works fine. But because I don't want to switch pages, I want to render the views in one page. Here is the problem. My Create form and List view works fine when I render them in one page. But when I also want to render my Edit form, I get errors.

One thing that happens is that the Create form puts de data in the database 2 times. Also when I don't put validated data in my form, the edit form appears at the same time that the create form is shown. The third problem is when I put the edit button in my List. The create form disappears and the edit form apears. So this works, but when I want to save the changed data, I get a hex string error. When I restart the application, the data isn't changed, but there is new record with the changed data.

I guess there is a problem with the id string. But I can't fix it.

So I have 4 views (index, create, list and edit)
Create, list and edit all have their own model.
And I use one controller for the views / models

The controller (CarsController):

```
public class CarsController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<Car> carsInDb = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindAll().ToList();
            return View(carsInDb.ConvertAllToViewModels());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(string id)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return View();
            }
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(InsertCarViewModel insertCarViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Car car = insertCarViewModel.ConvertToDomain();
                CarRentalContext.Cars.Insert(car);
                Response.Redirect("Cars", true);
            }
            return View(insertCarViewModel);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return null;
            }
            Car car = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));
            return View(car.ConvertToUpdateViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UpdateCarViewModel updateCarViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Car modifiedCar = updateCarViewModel.ConvertToDomain();
                CarRentalContext.Cars.Save(modifiedCar);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(updateCarViewModel);
        }
    }
```

The index view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.UpdateCarViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            @{Html.RenderAction("Create", Model);}
        </div>

        <div>
            @{Html.RenderAction("Edit", Model);}
        </div>

        <div>
            @{Html.RenderAction("List", Model);}
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of show/hide the views for create and edit views try to replace one with another, using ajax to get the result of the action. This way you will have only one view in the page.

Do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function renderActionInDiv(idcar, action)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action, //or "/Cars/Edit"
        data: { id = idcar},
        success: function (ajxData) {
            if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
                $("#div-editOrCreate").html(ajaxData);
            }
        },
        async: asyncCall
    });
}
</script>

    <a onclick='renderActionInDiv(3, "Edit")'>edit car<a/>

    <a onclick='renderActionInDiv(0, "Create")'>create new car<a/>

    <div id="div-editOrCreate">
     @{Html.RenderAction("Create", Model);}
    </div>
```

Comment: I have thought about using jQuery / Javascript. But I'm trying to find a solution without javascript

Comment: but how do you select the car to edit without javascript? how do you hide or show those views without javascript?! you need some js logic...

Comment: As you see in my code, when the id string is empty, I return null, so you don't see the view. When the id string is not empty, the Edit view wil show, and the Create view is null

Comment: If you return only one view, edit or create, then why are you saying "My Create form and List view works fine when I render them in one page. But when I also want to render my Edit form, I get errors." From this, I understand that you render list, create and edit.

Comment: Why you don't have only one action that check if the id is empty and return instead on null the Create view:

public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                 return View("Create");
            }
            Car car = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));

            return View(car.ConvertToUpdateViewModel());
}

This way you will render only one action for get and one action for save(post), where you can check if id is 0 then insert else update.

Comment: I have deleted my create form, and only use the edit form, this works fine! The biggest problem was the redirect